# Reduce the use of $this pseudo-variable in php?

Tags: php, refactoring, this

Any time I want to use an instance variable, I need to use the pseudovariable $this, am I correct? And if those are objects with methods, I'm still having to use them. So when I have an example like so:

```
class myClass{
    private $thingOne;
    private $thingTwo;

    public function __construct($thingOne,$thingTwo){
        $this->thingOne = $thingOne;
        $this->thingTwo = $thingTwo;
    }
}
```

And then I start adding methods to `myClass` I have to start typing things like:

```
$this->thingOne->doSomething($this->thingTwo->doSomethingElse());
```

But I would much rather type:

```
$thingOne->doSomething($thingTwo->doSomethingElse());
```

I just find writing this-> all the time to be annoying. Can't it just be assumed that I'm using the instance variables that I have given it? My code ends up having this this this this this this this everywhere.

Could I rename it to something shorter? $t or something?

Comment: `$this` is a reference to the current object and cannot be renamed. You can make your own reference variable, but you would still have to do it in every method. So you should just use `$this`, don't be so lazy.

Comment: And if you need to use:
    $this->thingOne->doSomething($this->thingTwo->doSomethingElse());
inside your object, that's probably a bad design or implementation.

Comment: $this also allows to make distinction between instance variable and a variable that is local to a function...

Comment: @MateuszSip Why is that? One shouldn't pass the return from one object method into a different object method's argument? What would this indicate to you?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Alright, I won't be lazy. But [some](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Wall) say [laziness](http://threevirtues.com/) is a virtue...

Comment: Laziness might be a good thing sometimes, but in this case laziness won't help you write labor-saving programs.

Comment: @Zimmi Yes I know, but when you're mostly using instance variables and not locals, you tend to have to use a lot of $this, and I was wondering if I could tighten up the code a bit somehow... I guess the answer is just no, I can't rename it or anything.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Feel free to add your comment as an answer so I may accept it if nobody finds some crazy hack in the next couple of hours to rename $this. Ha.

Comment: Go procedural style.

Comment: @adjenks
I have imagined some ugly and barely readable cases, so I overreacted.

If your methods are named properly and you don't use complex chains of calls, that's ok. Otherwise, you should move parts of your code to separate, coherent methods and call them.

Comment: @chba That's a valid suggestion and I appreciate your effort in trying to accomplish the goal I had in mind. I might be able to minimize my code if I write procedurally, but I like the organizational grouping of classes. This is something I like about object literal notation in javascript, it allows for creating extra namespaces as containers around functions, sort of like making singletons or static classes or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this` is a reference to the current class object and cannot be renamed. You could make your own reference variable, but you would have to declare it in every method, thus making it inefficient. Instead you should just regularly use `$this`.